# How to record time spent on page in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Due to the way GA tracks exits, it is actually not possible out of the box to get "time spent on page" metric from GA if the user does not navigate to the second page of the site.

I need a solution that meets the following requirements

1. Will work even if the user does not navigate to a second page (leave after visiting landing page)
2. Measure accurately time spent on page (taking into consideration of browser focus and idle)
3. Bonus - has an ability to not count towards bounce rate if the user stays for X seconds on page

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send a virtual pageview on exit intent. In this way the landing page will not be the exit page.